# Defining an XSD so that XML element will be type="array"

Tags: arrays, xml, xsd

My question relates to defining an XSD document. My specific issue is how to define the XSD so that when the XML is generated an element will have type="array".

Desired result would be something like:

```
<names type="array">
  <name>
  ......
  </name>
</names>
```

I have experimented using methods recommended on several forums, but from I have found it seems to me like there may not even be a type for array, which confuses me since a resulting XML element can have a type of array.

Comment: If you could recall, Can you please post how did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

There are tools that will take an XSD and generate a sample XML document that adheres to the XSD, but you should understand that the primary purpose of an XSD is to *validate* an XML document.

This XSD will validate your XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="names">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="type"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Note also that using a `type="array"` attribute-value pair is unconventional in the XML as type information is conveyed in the XSD in the content model for `names` and needn't be repeated explicitly in the XML document.